# Replace values of column by aggregation over groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's assume I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
   id   x    y        timestamp
   1   32   30        1031
   1   4    105       1035
   1   8    110       1050
   2   18   10        1500
   2   40   20        1550
   2   80   10        1450
....


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,1,2,2,2], [32,4,8,18,40,80], [30,105,110,10,20,10], [1031,1035,1050,1500,1550,1450]])).T
df.columns = ['id', 'x', 'y', 'timestamp']
```

I have now the following code:

```
df= df.groupby(["id"]).agg({
    'timestamp': lambda x: x.max() - x.min(),
    'x': 'mean',
    'y': 'mean'
}).reset_index()
```

Unfortunately, this is not what I want. I would like to have the following resulting dataframe:

```
id    x     y       timestamp
-----------------------------
1    32     30      19
1    4      105     19
1    8      110     19
2    10     10      100
2    40     20      100
2    80     10      100
....
```

That means the timestamp columns should be replace by the maximum - minimum value for each group (but I don't want to aggregate the whole group into single value).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you just need to [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and use numpy's [`peak-to-peak`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html)

```
df['timestamp'] = df.groupby(["id"]).timestamp.transform(np.ptp)
```

Comment: It works but I'm getting the warning: "FutureWarning: Method .ptp is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use numpy.ptp instead." How can I get rid of the warning?